# boost asio async_read header connection closes too early

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

Providing a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) is going to be hard, the scenario is the following:

- a server written in c++ with boost asio offers some services
- a client written in c++ with boost asio requests services

There are custom headers and most communication is done using multipart/form.
However, in the case where the server returns a 401 for an unauthorized access,
the client receives a broken pipe (system error 32).

AFAIK this happens when the server connection closes too early.
So, running into gdb, I can see that the problem is indeed the transition from the async_write which sends the request, to the async_read_until which reads the first line of the HTTP Header:

The `connect` routine sends the request from the client to the server:

```
    boost::asio::async_write(*socket_.get(),
                             request_,
                             boost::bind(&asio_handler<http_socket>::write_request, 
                                         this,
                                         boost::asio::placeholders::error,
                                         boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred));
```

And the `write_request` callback, checks if the request was sent OK, and then reads the first line (until the first newline):

```
template <class T> 
void asio_handler<T>::write_request(const boost::system::error_code & err,
                                    const std::size_t bytes)
{       
    if (!err) {
        // read until first newline
        boost::asio::async_read_until(*socket_,
                                      buffer_,
                                      "\r\n",
                                      boost::bind(&asio_handler::read_status_line, 
                                                  this, 
                                                  boost::asio::placeholders::error,
                                                  boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred));
    }
    else {
        end(err);       
    }
}
```

The problem is that the `end(err)` is always called with a broken pipe (error code 32). Meaning, as far as I understand, that the server closed the connection. The server indeed closes the connection, but only **after** it has sent a message `HTTP/1.1 401  Unauthorized`.

- using `curl` with the appropriate request, we do get the actual message/error before the server closes the connection
- using our client written in C++/boost asio we only get the broken pipe and no data
- only when the server leaves the connection open, do we get to the point of reading the error (401) but that defeats the purpose, since now the connection is left open.

I would really appreciate any hints or tips. I understand that without the code its hard to help, so I can add more source at any time.

## EDIT:

If I **do not** check for errors between writing the request, and reading the server reply, then I do get the actual HTTP 401 error. However this seems counter-intuitive, and I am not sure why this happens or if it is supposed to happen.

Comment: Does the server need to read the entire HTTP Request to determine and respond with unauthorized?  For example, perhaps authorization can be determined from only header fields, obviating the need to read any of the multipart/form body.  In that scenario, the server could send the response and close the connection before the client finishes writing the request.

Comment: @TannerSansbury No it only needs the header values to reply. And yes, that is what is happening, the server is replying before the entire request has been received. I assumed (yes I know...) that the reply would come after the server was finished receiving the request which obviously isn't the case. Many thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The observed behavior is allowed per the HTTP specification.

A client or server may close the socket at anytime.  The server can provide a response and close the connection before the client has finished transmitting the request.  When writing the body, it is recommended that clients monitor the socket for an error or close notification.  From the [RFC 7230, HTTP/1.1: Message Syntax and Routing Section 6.5. Failures and Timeouts](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230#section-6.5):

> **6.5.  Failures and Timeouts**
>
> > A client, server, or proxy MAY close the transport connection at any time.  [...]
> >
> > A client sending a message body SHOULD monitor the network connection for an error response while it is transmitting the request.  If the client sees a response that indicates the server does not wish to receive the message body and is closing the connection, the client SHOULD immediately cease transmitting the body and close its side of the connection.

On a graceful connection closure, the server will send a response to the client before closing the underlying socket:

> **6.6.  Tear-down**
>
> > A server that sends a "close" connection option MUST initiate a close of the connection [...] after it sends the response containing "close".  [...]

Given the above behaviors, there are three possible scenarios.  The `async_write()` operation completes with:

- success, indicating the request was written in full.  The client may or may not have received the HTTP Response yet
- an error, indicating the request was not written in full.  If there is data available to be read on the socket, then it may contain the HTTP Response sent by the server before the connection terminated.  The HTTP connection may have terminated gracefully
- an error, indicating the request was not written in full.  If there is no data available to be read on the socket, then the HTTP connection was not terminated gracefully

Consider either:

- initiating the `async_read()` operation if the `async_write()` is successful or there is data available to be read

  ```cpp
   void write_request(
     const boost::system::error_code & error,
     const std::size_t bytes_transferred)
   {
     // The server may close the connection before the HTTP Request finished
     // writing.  In that case, the HTTP Response will be available on the
     // socket.  Only stop the call chain if an error occurred and no data is
     // available.
     if (error && !socket_->available()) 
     {
       return;
     }

     boost::asio::async_read_until(*socket_, buffer_, "\r\n", ...);
  }
  ```
- per the RFC *recommendation*, initiate the `async_read()` operation at the same time as the `async_write()`.  If the server indicates the HTTP connection is closing, then the client would shutdown its send side of the socket.  The additional state handling may not warrant the extra complexity

Comment: many thanks for the thorough reply! I ended up taking the second approach, but I think I'll combine with the first just in case.